# Cambiar un valor dentro de un archivo por otro en shell

Tags: linux, shell

Tengo el siguiente valor en un archivo json y quiero cambiar su contenido

```
"image": "443d9049dgg8.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo:test_120404",
```

Mediante la función shell **sed** como puedo cambiar el contenido de **image** por IMAGE1_NAME filtrando unicamente por este valor: **443d9049dgg8**. dando como resultado lo siguiente:

```
"image": "IMAGE1_NAME",
```

Sed puede realizar esto, es decir, cambiar un valorA por un valorB buscando una unica parte del ValorA ??

Answer (score 0):

Sí, precisamente para eso sirven las expresiones regulares:

```
sed 's/443d9049dgg8[^"]*/IMAGE1_NAME"/' archivo
```

`[^"]*` significa: todo lo que esta después del valor buscado hasta que encuentra las comillas (excluidas).